# Android: Populate ListView directly from SQLite Database - without using ArrayList

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to populate a ListView from a SQLite Database without saving the data to an Array or List first? I have about 20000 lines of data in my SQLite Database.

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077955/android-using-simplecursoradapter-to-get-data-from-database-to-listview

Comment: Use a Cursor, you will have it with a query on your SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate your `ListView` directly from a database. To avoid performing database operations on the UI thread (`startManagingCursor` and `stopManagingCursor`), it is recommended to use a `CursorLoader` - backed by a `ContentProvider` -  in order to load data asynchronously. Read more... http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use CursorAdapter to achieve this. Here goes a tutorial: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html