# My Custom ArrayAdapter only shows the last Record

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

My Custome ArrayAdapter: This does what it is supposed to do but only shows the last record of the particular table. I need it to show all of the records

```
public class RecordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RecordData> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
RecordData data[] = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RecordAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, RecordData[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    RecordData record_item = data[position];
    holder.txtDate.setText(record_item.recDate);
    return row;
}

static class RecordHolder {
    TextView txtDate;
}
```

}

My OnClickListener:

```
String dateToSee = mDisplayDate.getText().toString().trim();
            MyRecordsDatabaseHandler db = new MyRecordsDatabaseHandler(this);
            // Querying all items
            List<RecordToDoActivity> items = db.getRecord(dateToSee);
            for (RecordToDoActivity ti : items) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= items.size(); i++) {
                    display_record_dateEditText.setText(ti.getDate());
                    display_record_timeEditText.setText(ti.getTime());
                    display_record_glucoseEditText.setText(ti.getReading());
                    display_record_glucoseTimeEditText.setText(ti.getReadtime());
                    display_record_mealTimeEditText.setText(ti.getMealTime());
                    display_record_medsEditText.setText(ti.getMeds());
                    //display_record_insulin_unit_text.setText(ti.get());
                    display_record_moodEditText.setText(ti.getMood());
                    display_record_weatherEditText.setText(ti.getWeather());
                    display_record_notesEditText.setText(ti.getNote()
                    );
                }
            }
            if (!display_record_dateEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_timeEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_glucoseEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_glucoseTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_mealTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_medsEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_moodEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_weatherEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&
                    !display_record_notesEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ) {
                RecordData record_data[] = new RecordData[] {
                        new RecordData("Date: "+display_record_dateEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Time: "+display_record_timeEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Reading: "+display_record_glucoseEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Reading Time: "+display_record_glucoseTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Meal: "+display_record_mealTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Medication: "+display_record_medsEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Mood: "+display_record_moodEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Weather: "+display_record_weatherEditText.getText().toString().trim()+ "\n"+
                                "Notes: "+display_record_notesEditText.getText().toString().trim()),

                };
                RecordAdapter adapter = new RecordAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.listview_record_row, record_data);
                listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
            }//end ITEM_ONE if statement
```

I have tried each of the item individually and they are all displaying data. But I cannot figure out how to get it to display all of the records into the One list view

The ListView is a normal ListView encapsulated in a LinearLayout:

Help.... Im really stuck on this. Thanks

Comment: your data model is sqlite db, so why dont you use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have now created a SimpleCursorAdapter and it is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving you data from a DB, so you should use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) or implement you own CursorAdapter.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12078768/4871489) probably will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Tin Megali for your suggestion. I have created a SimpleCursorAdapter and it is working well.