# Populate spinner from simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I have some trouble to populate spinner from sqlite database with simple cursor adapter. I must use simple cursor adapter not array adapter. My MainActivity, functions and xml files are as follows:

```
  public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


    private Spinner workerId = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    c = getCursor();

    String[] columns = new String[]{Database.mylist};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.spinner };
    myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, columns,to, 0);
    workerId.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    ..............
    ..............
    }
```

Function is below:

```
    public Cursor getCursor() {
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from " + Database.mylist + " where isCancel = 0", null);
    return c;
}
```

Xml file is below;

```
        MainActivity.xml


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And when I run app the following screen displays. There is data but it seems empty.  I have _id, name columns.

[empty spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Pyd.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `Database.myList` pointing to the name of a table, or the name of a column? Because you use it as both. Have you checked to see whether your `getCursor()` method returns a `Cursor` with any rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.spinner };
```

to

```
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
```

And you can read a little bit more about SimpleCursorAdapter here: [Android: Using SimpleCursorAdapter to get Data from Database to ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077955/android-using-simplecursoradapter-to-get-data-from-database-to-listview#12078768)

Also you are using Database.mylist as column name and table name as PPartisan pointed out in a comment.

Comment: String[] columns = new String[]{Database.mylist}; will be String[] columns = new String[]{Database.col_name}; I did write it wrong. But it does not solve problem.

Comment: Thanks Josef. Now it Works.