# How can I get the ID of the ListView Item instead of the position on the listview?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the ID in the database when i long press an Item in my listview, however when I long press and Item i get the position of that Item on the listview e.g: Cake has ID =3 but it's the first on the list since i deleted two entries, now the ID received by the delete function is ID = 1

```
    public class ViewPantry extends AppCompatActivity {
        private DataBaseManager mydManager;
        private ListView itemRec;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pantry);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            mydManager = new DataBaseManager(ViewPantry.this);
            itemRec = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemrec);
            itemRec.setOnItemLongClickListener(new                                 
    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,                 
    View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a + "                     
    selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    removeRecs(position);
                    return false;
                }
            });



            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ViewPantry.this,         
    MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            showRec();

        }

        public boolean showRec() {
            mydManager.openReadable();
            ArrayList<String> tableContent = mydManager.retrieveRows();
            //response.setText("The rows in the products table are: \n");
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>        
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tableContent);
            itemRec.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean removeRecs(int id) {
            boolean result = mydManager.deleteRow(id);
            if(result == true) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewPantry.this, "Item Deleted" + id, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ViewPantry.this, "Error" + id,         
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            showRec();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use a `CursorAdapter` instead – e.g., `SimpleCursorAdapter` – and you get the ID automagically in `onItemLongClick()` as the `long id` parameter.

Comment: You mean this ? onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,

Comment: Yep. If you were to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead, the `long id` passed into that method would be the ID.

Comment: Could you post an Example as an answer ?, Im not quite sure I understand where to put that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `OnItemLongClickListener` and its `onItemLongClick()` method would stay just as you have them. It's the `ArrayAdapter<String>` that you would change to a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and your dataset would change from an `ArrayList<String>` to a `Cursor` with the ID column, and whichever column you're currently using in `retrieveRows()`. There's a basic example of setting up a `SimpleCursorAdapter` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12078768/2850651.

Comment: Hi, do you use a list of custom POJO/model in theListView adapter?

Answer (score -1):

Try logging itemRec. That is the reference to the long ID of the item itself. This should produce desired effect.  Post your results please.

Comment: `itemRec` is the `ListView`, not any data item.